# WZZIP create zip file excluding 2 folder + subfolders

Tags: batch-file, winzip

I have both winzip and the command line addon installed and I am trying to write a .bat file to zip up a certain folder on one of my drives. What I would like is create a zip from a folder but I need to exclude 2 folders (with subfolders) from the zip. The code I have so far that works is:

```
wzzip -r -p "H:\Temp\Files Backup".zip "D:\test folder 1\"
```

I would like it to missed folders D:\test folder\sub folder 4\ & D:\test folder\sub folder 9\ but zip up all the other folders and sub folders.

I have tried:

```
wzzip -r -p "H:\Temp\Files Backup".zip "D:\test folder 1\" -x "D:\test folder\sub folder 4\" "D:\test folder\sub folder 9\"
```

But that errors saying "ERROR: missing string after option -x 
Program is terminating!

Also tried:

```
wzzip -r -p "H:\Temp\Files Backup".zip "D:\test folder 1\" -x"D:\test folder\sub folder 4\" "D:\test folder\sub folder 9\"
wzzip -r -p "H:\Temp\Files Backup".zip "D:\test folder 1\" -x:"D:\test folder\sub folder 4\" "D:\test folder\sub folder 9\"
wzzip -r -p "H:\Temp\Files Backup".zip "D:\test folder 1\" -xd:"D:\test folder\sub folder 4\" "D:\test folder\sub folder 9\"
```

I don't what else to try as if I use winzip32 the syntax is different and if I use 7zip it is different again

Comment: To start with, I'd suggest that you do not suffix paths with trailing backslashes, they rarely necessary, and in some instances can be seen as escape characters for the doublequotes that follow them. As far as I know, the exclude function, `[-|/]x<filename>`, is for files, but as it accepts wildcards, you could try `/x"*sub folder 4\*"`. I have no idea if this will work, or even if it does whether your archive will still store the folder(s) as empty.

Comment: yeah my original code didn't work because winzip doesn't work with folders it works with files only. I've added my final solution cheers for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Compo this was my final solution:

```
wzzip -r -p "H:\Temp\Files Backup".zip "D:\test folder 1" -x"D:\test folder 1\sub folder 4\*" -x"D:\test folder 1\sub folder 9\*"
```